# HarpJS shared partial won't render on pages above index in directory

Tags: pug, partials, harp

I'm trying to build a static HTML site using HarpJS and have got it ALMOST completely nailed.

For some reason, the two pages in my public directory that are alphabetically before my index.jade file (About.jade and Contact.jade) won't render the partial "footer.jade" in the _shared directory.

Every other page renders the partial with no issue using:

```
!= partial(_shared/footer)
```

But I don't understand why it's not populating any code on the About or Contact page.

I have confirmed that the code above is written exactly the same, the indentations are the same - but nothing comes out!

Comment: try [`include`](http://jade-lang.com/reference/includes/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you happen to be using quotes on the `index.jade` file but not in `about.jade` and `contact.jade`? I think switching to the following would fix it:

```
!= partial("_shared/footer")
```

Comment: Yep - that was totally it. Thank you!